# How to keep ties when using dplyr distinct function?

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, distinct, rank

I'm using dplyr `distinct()` with multiple variables and am trying to figure out how to handle "ties". For example, when running the code at the bottom of this post against example data frame `label_1`, I'd like to get these results in situations like this where there's a tie with `eleCnt` and `grpID` variables:

```
  Element Group   eleCnt   grpID grpRnk  Explain grpRnk column...
  <chr>   <dbl>    <int>   <int>  <int>
1 R           1        1       3      1  Ranked 1st since it has lowest eleCnt & lowest grpID
2 X           3        1       3      1  Also ranked 1st since it ties with above in terms of eleCnt and grpID
3 R           2        3       7      2  Ranked 2nd since its eleCnt is 2nd and its grpRnk is 2nd
```

When I run the code against data frame `label_2`, there are no ties and the code gives me this correct output:

```
  Element Group eleCnt grpID grpRnk 
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1 B           2      1     3      1
2 R           3      1     6      2
3 X           4      1    10      3
4 R           1      4     9      4
5 R           2      6    13      5
```

Any recommendations for an efficient way to do this, preferably in `dplyr`? Maybe `distinct()` isn't the right function to be using?

Code:

```
library(dplyr)

label_1 <- data.frame(Element=c("B","R","R","R","R","B","X","X","X","X","X"),
                      Group = c(0,1,1,2,2,0,3,3,0,0,0),
                      eleCnt = c(1,1,2,3,4,2,1,2,3,4,5),
                      grpID = c(0,3,3,7,7,0,3,3,0,0,0))

label_2 <- data.frame(Element = c("R","R","R","X","X","X","X","B","B","R","R","R","R"),
                       Group = c(3,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,1,1,2,2),
                       eleCnt = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,4,5,6,7),
                       grpID = c(6,6,6,10,10,10,10,3,3,9,9,13,13))

label_2 %>% select(Element,Group,eleCnt,grpID) %>% 
  filter(Group > 0) %>% 
  group_by(Element,Group) %>% 
  slice(which.min(Group)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(eleCnt,grpID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(eleCnt,grpID) %>%
  mutate(grpRnk = 1:n())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can leverage `data.table::rleid()` function, like this:

```
f <- function(lab) {
  filter(lab,Group!=0) %>% 
    arrange(eleCnt,grpID) %>% 
    mutate(grpRnk = data.table::rleid(eleCnt,grpID)) %>% 
    group_by(grpID) %>% 
    filter(grpRnk==min(grpRnk))
}
```

Apply `f()` to `label_1`

```
f(label_1)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   grpID [2]
  Element Group eleCnt grpID grpRnk
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1 R           1      1     3      1
2 X           3      1     3      1
3 R           2      3     7      3
```

Apply `f()` to `label_1`

```
f(label_2)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   grpID [5]
  Element Group eleCnt grpID grpRnk
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1 B           2      1     3      1
2 R           3      1     6      2
3 X           4      1    10      3
4 R           1      4     9      9
5 R           2      6    13     12
```

Comment: Hi langtang, could you pls double check? Per my OP I'm trying to get the grpRnk column when running the code for label_1 to be 1, 1, 2, and for label_2 to be 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: Adding to the end of your code mutate(grpRank= match(grpID, unique(grpID))) gets the desired results, but is it good practice to write over an existing column (grpRnk) like this?

Comment: you can also add  `... %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(grpRnk=data.table::rleid(grpID))`